# What is a remote hacking device takedown point?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

The *Terminal Velocity* AR predator challenge requires that I "use a remote hacking device takedown point to KO a militia thug." **What is a remote hacking device takedown point and how do I use it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that Challenge to get that. There is portable generators around use the remote hacking device to make it explode when a militia thug is nearby to kill him there is a star

All this has been referenced from here http://webjunkiesblog.blogspot.com.au/2015/06/batman-arkham-knight-complete-ar.html